# Why I keep getting: JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed with Apollo 4

Tags: node.js, graphql, jwt, apollo, apollo-server

I'm using Auth0 and Apollo Server 4 (just updated to new version) and for some reason I get this error when validating my bearer token:"JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed"

The docs says its because "the token does not have three components (delimited by a .)" and it appears that my token is missing one component since there is two ".." in it.

Here's the bearer"eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYteWpkczdzMHcudXMuYXV0aDAuY29tLyJ9..ra0kpvVLjOY5SXNL.QcHMSTrOB1gewFkjwJdg3MHCr0UfdS0tKA2XdskUKp8_10puH_oq6meSs9x6f_LDZHeYfJso8QaofxDhNvlpWU2zQFbmPD_tJtTui4jCqNFpYM6Aapw6d7ADeckl0vjsBVs9AdJHUF_6tlBtI6s8Qk6r4UtufKSGfpm5ucb2FeCz-9DREH19QGCBzundoi5goSKK4Br8VhZTrP89KZDwQYSYWR-SXXrAUSz3mhDPbYQjrPeyVZtt4WCHwgCweF-iLHkMI6g82zKYbNUHImfcSZcmNgYS3sTL6MkKLKr9oOkgLyR0KDA2r22vKracFdoZB0g.Lk0ClIc1usAEXFaGzO-hDg"

Here's my server code:

```js
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import resolvers from './graphql/Resolvers.js';
import { typeDefs } from './graphql/gqlSchema.js';
import verifyToken from './verifyToken.js';
import config from './config.cjs';
import startMongo from './Mongo/StartMongo.js';

const server = new ApolloServer({
  cors: { origin: 'https://www.timerwise.com' },
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});
const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    let isAuthenticated = false;
    let token;

    try {
      const authHeader = req.headers.authorization || '';

      if (authHeader) {
        const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

        const payload = await verifyToken(token);
        isAuthenticated = payload && payload.sub ? true : false;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    return { req, auth: { token, isAuthenticated } };
  },
  listen: { port: config.PORT },
});

startMongo();

console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
```

Here's my token validation code:

```js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

import jwksClient from 'jwks-rsa';
import config from './config.cjs';

const verifyToken = async (bearerToken) => {
  const client = jwksClient({ jwksUri: `https://${config.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json` });

  function getJwksClientKey(header, callback) {
    client.getSigningKey(header.kid, function (error, key) {
      const signingKey = key.publicKey || key.rsaPublicKey;
      callback(null, signingKey);
    });
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.verify(
      bearerToken,
      getJwksClientKey,
      {
        audience: config.AUDIENCE,
        issuer: `https://${config.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/`,
        algorithms: ['RS256'],
      },
      function (err, decoded) {
        console.log(bearerToken);
        if (err) reject(err);
        resolve(decoded);
      }
    );
  });
};

export default verifyToken;
```

I recently update to Apollo Server 4 and the problems started. But for the life of me, I can't figure out whats wrong.

Comment: The token that you show there is indeed not a standard (only signed) JWT with 3 segments (JWS), but a JWE (the encrypted form of JWT. A JWE has 5 segments, in your case the second segment, which would have an encrypted key, is empty, that's why you see two dots. With 'jsonwebtoken' you can't handle JWE. It expects a JWS and considers the JWE 'malformed'. Take a look at github.com/panva/jose for examples. That package can deal with JWE. And you need to find the symmetric key somewhere to decrypt your token.

Comment: Hey thanks. I just followed Auth0 setup and they use jsonwebtoken and jwks-rsa in all their example. Don't know why I'm getting an empty encrypted key. I looked into Jose but it didn't seem to solve the problem. I'll give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: So the error was that I was calling an opaque token (without providing an audience). I should have used the `authorizationParams` object with `getAccessTokenSilently`.

Here's the front-end updated code:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider, HttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

import { config } from '../../env';

function ApolloWrapper({ children }) {
  const { isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const [bearerToken, setBearerToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getToken = async () => {
      try {
        const options = { authorizationParams: { audience: config.REACT_APP_AUDIENCE } }; //-->modification here
      
        const token = isAuthenticated ? await getAccessTokenSilently(options) : '';
        setBearerToken(token);
        console.log(token);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Failed to fetch token', err);
      }
    };
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      getToken();
    } else {
      setBearerToken('');
    }
  }, [getAccessTokenSilently, isAuthenticated]);

  const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: config.GRAPHQL_URI });

  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers, ...rest }) => {
    if (!bearerToken) return { headers, ...rest };
    return {
      ...rest,
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${bearerToken}`,
      },
    };
  });

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  });

  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
}

export default ApolloWrapper;
```